# Remove everything but the last part of an element

Tags: python, list

If I have a list:

```
['12 13 0 21 0.3','2 3 0 1 0.1','12 19 0 2 0.9','22 33 0 3 0.5']
```

How can I remove everything bar the last part of each element so the list becomes:

```
['0.3','0.1','0.9','0.5']
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can go this way using [`list comprehensions`](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and [`rsplit`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rsplit):

```
l = ['12 13 0 21 0.3','2 3 0 1 0.1','12 19 0 2 0.9','22 33 0 3 0.5']

print([s.rsplit(' ', 1)[1] for s in l])
```

Output:

```
['0.3', '0.1', '0.9', '0.5']
```

Answer (score 5):

Make use of a Python list comprehension, like so:

```
l = ['12 13 0 21 0.3','2 3 0 1 0.1','12 19 0 2 0.9','22 33 0 3 0.5']
print [x.rsplit(' ', 1)[1] for x in l]

> ['0.3', '0.1', '0.9', '0.5']
```

Comment: +1, `str.rsplit()` is a little better than splitting the whole string here.

Answer (score 1):

That would work, it uses list comprehensive methods:

```
list = [i[-3:len(i)] for i in ['12 13 0 2.1', '2.3 43 4.4']]
```